# Azure container group 2 containers with 2 external ports. 2nd container always terminates

Tags: yaml, terraform, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to deploy an Azure container instance with multiple external ports.  I've tried the following terraform code:

```html
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "experiment" {
  name     = "experiment"
  location = "west europe"
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "nginx" {
  name                = "nginx-test-terraform"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.experiment.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.experiment.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = "nginx-test-terraform"

  container {
    name   = "nginx"
    image  = "nginx"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "0.5"
    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = "nginx2"
    image  = "nginx"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "0.5"
    ports {
      port     = 81
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

However, the 2nd container always fails with the following error:

[emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Is there anyway i can correct this in the file, or is this a limitation with Terraform at the moment?

I've tried the same with a Yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: 2018-10-01
name: dockercompose-exp-01
location: westeurope
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
properties:
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  containers:
  - name: helloworld-ms
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 0.5
          memoryInGB: 0.5
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
  - name: helloworld-nginx
    properties:
      image: nginx
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 0.5
          memoryInGB: 0.5
      ports:
      - port: 81
        protocol: TCP
  ipAddress:
    ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 81
      protocol: TCP
    type: Public
    dnsNameLabel: dockercompose-exp-01
```

and the same happens.

Therefore, it looks like it's either a limitation of the platform or I've got some sort of syntax error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the ACI does not support port mapping. You only can expose the ports directly. And the port is unique.

So the mistake you made is that the Nginx image exposes the port 80 in the Dockerfile, but you want to expose port 81 for the second one. Then it cannot respond on port 81. I recommend that do not deploy the same image in one container group, it's useless.

Comment: Got it Charles thanks. So i need to make sure the port is exposed correctly in the dockerfile first.